# Oracle schedule job error in plsql quotes

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, jobs

I'm trying to run this job:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
            job_name => '"TOCBA"."MAANDELIJKS_AFBOEKING"',
            job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
            job_action => 'DECLARE

V_SALDO_CREDIT NUMBER;
V_SALDO_STUD NUMBER;
V_LIMIET NUMBER;
V_REKENINGNUMMER NUMBER;
V_CRED_ID NUMBER;
V_STU_ID NUMBER;

BEGIN
FOR R IN (SELECT r2.REKENINGNUMMER AS REKNUMMER FROM Rekening r1 INNER JOIN Rekening r2 ON r1.REKENINGNUMMER = R2.REKENINGNUMMER and r1.REKENINGTYPE = 22 and r2.REKENINGTYPE = 41)
LOOP
   SELECT SALDO, BETAALLIMIET, REKENINGNUMMER, REKENINGID INTO V_SALDO_CREDIT, V_LIMIET, V_REKENINGNUMMER, V_CRED_ID FROM REKENING WHERE REKENINGNUMMER = R.REKNUMMER AND REKENINGTYPE = 41;
   SELECT REKENINGID INTO V_STU_ID FROM REKENING WHERE REKENINGNUMMER = R.REKNUMMER AND REKENINGTYPE = 22;
   V_SALDO_STUD := V_LIMIET -V_SALDO_CREDIT;

   UPDATE REKENING SET SALDO = (SELECT BETAALLIMIET FROM REKENING WHERE REKENINGNUMMER = V_REKENINGNUMMER AND REKENINGTYPE = 41) WHERE REKENINGNUMMER = R.REKNUMMER AND REKENINGTYPE = 41;
   UPDATE REKENING SET SALDO = SALDO - V_SALDO_STUD WHERE REKENINGNUMMER = R.REKNUMMER AND REKENINGTYPE = 22;

   INSERT INTO TRANSACTIE(REKENINGID, BEDRAG, DATUM, IBAN_PARTIJ2, OMSCHRIJVING, TYPE) VALUES (V_STU_ID, V_SALDO_STUD,SYSDATE, V_CRED_ID, "Maandelijkse afboeking " || to_char(sysdate, "Month"), "MND");

   INSERT INTO TRANSACTIE(REKENINGID, BEDRAG, DATUM, IBAN_PARTIJ2, OMSCHRIJVING, TYPE) VALUES (V_CRED_ID, V_SALDO_STUD,SYSDATE, V_STU_ID, "Maandelijkse afboeking " || to_char(sysdate, "Month"), "MND");
END LOOP;
END;',
            number_of_arguments => 0,
            start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2018-11-05 14:15:02.000000000 EUROPE/BERLIN','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR'),
            repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;BYDAY=MON',
            end_date => NULL,
            enabled => FALSE,
            auto_drop => FALSE,
            comments => 'geen');




    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
             name => '"TOCBA"."MAANDELIJKS_AFBOEKING"', 
             attribute => 'store_output', value => TRUE);
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
             name => '"TOCBA"."MAANDELIJKS_AFBOEKING"', 
             attribute => 'logging_level', value => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_OFF);




    DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(
             name => '"TOCBA"."MAANDELIJKS_AFBOEKING"');
END;
```

The PL/SQL code is tested and working fine without the Job. When i try to run it like this I'm getting the following error:

```
"ORA-06550: Regel 20, kolom 198:
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: Kolom is hier niet toegestaan..
ORA-06550: Regel 20, kolom 4:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored.
ORA-06550: Regel 22, kolom 198:
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: Kolom is hier niet toegestaan..
ORA-06550: Regel 22, kolom 4:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored.
"
```

When I remove the two insert (TRANSACTIES) statements is working fine. I guess the problem is happening because of the quotes. Anyone here that knows how to solve this?

Comment: in english the error mean : ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Comment: You need to use single quotes to denote strings, not double-quotes.

Comment: Please put `DBMS_SESSION.SET_NLS('NLS_LANGUAGE', 'american');` at begin of the block, then the error messages should be in english. Or run `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = 'american';` before you create the job.

Comment: I would recommend to write a procedure with all the stuff and execute this procedure with a single command in Job scheduler.

Comment: Is this correct, you like to execute the job every minute but only on Mondays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your problem. The problem is with using single quotes inside the big single quotes in `job_action =>`. You need to write every single quote twice (e.g., instead of `'` write `''`). It is not a double quote but rather a single quote written twice. Therefore, your insert statements will look like the following:

```
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIE(REKENINGID, BEDRAG, DATUM, IBAN_PARTIJ2, OMSCHRIJVING, TYPE) 
VALUES (V_STU_ID, V_SALDO_STUD,SYSDATE, V_CRED_ID, ''Maandelijkse afboeking '' || to_char(sysdate, ''Month''), ''MND'');

INSERT INTO TRANSACTIE(REKENINGID, BEDRAG, DATUM, IBAN_PARTIJ2, OMSCHRIJVING, TYPE) 
VALUES (V_CRED_ID, V_SALDO_STUD,SYSDATE, V_STU_ID, ''Maandelijkse afboeking '' || to_char(sysdate, ''Month''), ''MND'');
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as you noticed the problem in the single quotes, do like the below example:

The single quotes is used to close Varchar (literal) and date values, the double quote is used to enclose table, columns.. . That's why it pops error column not allowed here using double quotes.

```
DECLARE

V_SALDO_CREDIT NUMBER;
V_SALDO_STUD NUMBER;
V_LIMIET NUMBER;
V_REKENINGNUMMER NUMBER;
V_CRED_ID NUMBER;
V_STU_ID NUMBER;

BEGIN


   INSERT INTO TRANSACTIE
     (REKENINGID, BEDRAG, DATUM, IBAN_PARTIJ2, OMSCHRIJVING, TYPE)
   VALUES
     (V_STU_ID,
      V_SALDO_STUD,
      SYSDATE,
      V_CRED_ID,
      'Maandelijkse afboeking ' || to_char(sysdate, 'Month'),
      'MND');

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also Alternative Quoting Mechanism (''Q'') for String Literals

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CIREYU9EA54EOKQ7LAMZKRF6P.html